# add new attribute to helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, yq

I need to add an attribute subdomain to a pod in a deployment template file, and to add it , I used yq for that , and here it is

```
yq4 eval --inplace '.spec.template.spec +=  {"subdomain": "{{.Values.global.deployment.subdomain}}"}'  test.yml
```

I got it in the below format and it is not true:

```
      subdomain: '{{{{}}.Values.global.deployment.subdomain{{}}}}'
```

but I need it to be rendered in this format:

```
     subdomain:  {{ .Values.global.deployment.subdomain }}
```

is there any help?

Comment: Can't reproduce it locally. Can you provide the test.yaml you are trying this on?

Comment: I am installing this helm charthttps://github.com/pegasystems/pega-helm-charts, then use the yq to add subdomain into one of the generated files @Inian